# Combine two query results with different columns into one

Tags: neo4j, combinations, union

I m trying to union/combine 2 query results with different relationship types that should stay separate afterwards (sub queries r2, r3 not the same column names). I want to get an output graph with c, p, r2, r3.

I tried the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Sample)-[r3:`Age`]->(c:Sample)
WHERE
r3.age >= 50
RETURN p, r3, c 
UNION 
MATCH (p:Sample)-[r1:`Age`]->(c:Sample)
MATCH (p:Sample)-[r2:`Size`]->(c:Sample)
WHERE
(r2.size <= 50 and r1.age >= 20)
return p, r2, c
```

The error message is:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: All sub queries in an UNION must have _
the same column names (line 5, column 1 (offset: 98))
"UNION "
```

The result should look like this table:

```
    p |   r2  | r3   | c 
  ------------------------
   p1 |       | sth  | c1
   p1 |  sth  |      | c1 
   ...|  ...  |  ... | ...
```

Comment: So, which one is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. The trick is to create empty columns to align the column names, so that UNION can work:
Add: **NULL as r2** and **NULL as r3** to the specific return.s

```
MATCH (p:Sample)-[r3:`Age`]->(c:Sample)
WHERE
r3.age >= 50
RETURN p, NULL as r2,  r3, c

UNION 

MATCH (p:Sample)-[r1:`Age`]->(c:Sample)
MATCH (p:Sample)-[r2:`Size`]->(c:Sample)
WHERE
(r2.size <= 50 and r1.age >= 20)
return p, r2, NULL as r3, c
```